# Create Function in Free App Service Plan using PowerShell

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

How do I create an Azure Function in an App Service Plan that has a 'Free' SKU.

`New-AzFunctionApp` seems to default to an alwaysOn Function, which is not supported with the Free SKU. Used to be that `-Properties @{alwaysOn=$False}` did the trick, but that is is no longer available. Tried the -AppSettings but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is an open [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/8388) regarding the ability to create function app with AlwaysOn=false in Powershell. The easier option is to use an ARM template which works fine as the way you want. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-function-app-create-dedicated

But if you want to stick to ps cmdlets, as a workaround, you can do the below.

1. Create the "App Service Plan" with "Basic" SKU separately
2. Create function app by passing the plan created above as param to `New-AzFunctionApp`. This would now have AlwaysOn=true.
3. Update the function app to have AlwaysOn=false.
4. Update the app service plan to "Free" tier.

Below are the example PS commands doing the above steps, update the params accordingly.

```
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "myRGName" -Name "myFuncAppName" -Location "West US"  -Tier "Basic"

New-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName "myRGName" -Name "myFuncAppName" -PlanName "myFuncAppName" -StorageAccountName "myStorageName" -Runtime Dotnet # update Runtime as per your need

$funcApp = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'microsoft.web/sites' -ResourceGroupName 'myRGName' -ResourceName 'myFuncAppName'
$funcApp | Set-AzResource -PropertyObject @{"siteConfig" = @{"AlwaysOn" = $false}} -Force

Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'myFuncAppName' -ResourceGroupName 'myRGName' -Tier Free -WorkerSize Small
```

Comment: BTW, creating a PowerShell 7 Function with version 3 is not working. Stating it's not supported, pointing to a page that list this combination as supported.

Comment: The reason I am asking, it worked for me: `New-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName "myRGName" -Name "myFuncAppName" -PlanName "myFuncAppName" -StorageAccountName "myStorageName" -Runtime Powershell`

Comment: Here we go, works when not using -RuntimeVersion:
```New-AzFunctionApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $FunctionName -FunctionsVersion 3 -Runtime Powershell -RuntimeVersion 7 -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -Location WestEurope```

Error:
Powershell version 7 in Functions version 3 for Windows is not supported. For supported languages, please visit 
'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages'.

Comment: can you try runtime version as "7.0"? When I do not specify it, it says "RuntimeVersion not specified. Setting default runtime version for Powershell to '7.0'.". So I tried "7.0" instead of 7, and it works :)

Comment: Could have sworn that was the first thing I tired. Might have not worked because I didn't pass as string. My bad, sorry about this.

Comment: No problem. Also wondering if using ARM template is an option for you. Updated the answer to include that.